# setTransform return unhandled

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-hydro, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp line 123 in TransformListener::subscription_callback_impl(...) the call buffer_.setTransform returns a boolean. If I've read things right it appears like that the return value should be checked, and handled in some way (error message if false??)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107051/settransform-return-unhandled/) by [robotiqsguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/9521/robotiqsguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general it's very unlikely to happen and there's not much else to do about it if it fails.

The only thing I could see is to add a debug output there if it fails. I'd merge a patch for that.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotiqsguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/9521/robotiqsguy/) on 2013-12-07**:
I think that it is reasonable to add debug output in there. If for some reason it does fail I think its better to know about it than not.